# "Timer Already Cancelled", but resumes when a new fragment is opened?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a list of train schedules. The list of train schedules is a fragment, and by clicking a schedule, a timetable opens up which itself is another fragment.

Lets call them `resultFragment` and `timetableFragment`.

I'm running a `timerTask` on the `timetableFragment`, which updates the live running information every 30 seconds.

Declared at the top of the fragment, within the fragment class, is:

```
private val trainScheduleUpdater: Timer = Timer()
```

Function `getSchedule()` is called in my `onCreateView` and does the following:

```
trainScheduleUpdater.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            timerTask {
                getActivity()?.runOnUiThread {
                    Log.i("trainTimer", "Timer Has Run for service $ctuid")
                }
            }, 0, 10000
        )
```

*Where $ctuid is an ID unique to the timetable which is open within the fragment.*

**My Problem**

When I close the timetable fragment, using a back press, and open another timetable from a result list, the timertask continues to run on the newly opened timetable, and so I get Logcat reports for both the timetables.

When I attempt to call either in the `onStop` or `onDestroy` the `trainScheduleUpdater.cancel()` command, it crashes stating the timer has already been cancelled (presumably through closure of the fragment).

Its therefore possible that the old train timetable fragment is not being removed. Here is the code which I am using on the RecyclerView which displays a list of train services (to which an onClick opens the respective timetable train fragment).

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener{
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val activity=v!!.context as AppCompatActivity
        bundle.putString("ctuid", item.ciftrainid)
        bundle.putString("date", item.rundate)
        trainfragment.arguments = bundle
        val fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)

        val oldFragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("train")
        if(oldFragment != null){
            fragment.remove(oldFragment)
            Log.i("fragment removal", "train fragment removed")
        }else{
            Log.i("fragment removal", "train fragment WAS NOT removed")

        }
        fragment.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, trainfragment, "train")
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
    }
})
```

In all attempts, Logcat produces the message that the `timetableFragment` fragment was not removed.

I'm guessing that the train `timetableFragment` fragment ceases to exist after using `.replace`, but the timer for that previous fragment is somehow not being destroyed and reinstated with the new `timetableFragment`?

Kind Regards

Comment: Don’t run timers in Fragments. Fragments are ephemeral, transient, reusable, etc. Do that kind of work in a ViewModel.

Comment: I think You are retaining instance of `trainfragment` as a field in class.
In this case, the FragmentManager does an optimization and the same fragment instance is used

Comment: For some reason running the timer on the function call rather than within the function itself, appears to resolve the issue. If anyone is able to post that as an answer and an explaintation as to why that would be much appreciated. Thanks